# cant include linux/cred.h header file: "No such file or directory"

Tags: c, linux, header, include, kernel

im currently trying to include the cred.h header file because I want to rewrite the uid, guid, ... which are inside the struct cred. But the include fails with the error message "fatal error: linux/cred.h: No such file or directory". I guess this happens because I cant include kernel header files to a user space program. Is there any way to solve this problem?

---

Update:

ah I forgot to mention that I want to compile it using the android ndk-build command, but there is a similiar optionn
the find command gives this output:

```
sudo find / -name cred.h
/tmp/mozilla_alex0/cred.h
/home/alex/Android/Sdk/goldfish/include/linux/cred.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-4.4.0-24/include/linux/cred.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-4.4.0-21/include/linux/cred.h
```

now I tried the following:

```
$ ndk-build -I /usr/src/linux-headers-4.4.0-21/include/linux/ 
[armeabi] Compile thumb  : futex_exploit <= exploit.c
/home/alex/Android/libfutex_exploit-master/libfutex_exploit-master/jni/exploit.c:34:18: fatal error: cred.h: No such file or directory
 #include <cred.h>
                  ^
compilation terminated.
```

when try to compile the file with gcc I get the same error:

```
$ gcc -I/usr/src/linux-headers-4.4.0-21/include/linux/ exploit.c -o exploit
In file included from /usr/include/stdio.h:33:0,
                 from exploit.c:21:
/usr/src/linux-headers-4.4.0-21/include/linux/stddef.h:4:31: fatal error: uapi/linux/stddef.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

Answer (score 2):

Find required file cred.h and put in the folders the compiler will search for it.

```
gcc ..... -I<include folder> .....
```